# Expect Script wait Command Hangs

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I have an expect script embedded in a bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# this function runs a command like 'ssh' and provides the password
function with_password {
expect << END
spawn $2
expect *assword:*
send -- $1
interact
wait
END
}

# run "long_running_command" on the remote server
with_password my_password "ssh my_user@some-server long_running_command"

# rsync some data to the remote server
with_password my_password "rsync /some/dir my_user@some-server:/remote/dir"

# run some other random command
with_password my_password "ssh my_user@some-server some_other_command"
```

The problem is that sometimes the script will hang while waiting for a spawned command.  If I
leave the `wait` command out of the expect script, the command will continue to run on the remote
server, but the bash script will continue, and I have no way of knowing when it finishes.

Why does my expect script seem to be randomly hanging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `interact` command in the `expect` here-doc was the problem.  I needed to wait for EOF instead:

```
#! /bin/bash

# this function runs a command like 'ssh' and provides the password
function with_password {
expect << END
set timeout 900
spawn $2
expect *assword:*
send -- $1
expect EOF
END
}

# run "long_running_command" on the remote server
with_password my_password "ssh my_user@some-server long_running_command"

# rsync some data to the remote server
with_password my_password "rsync /some/dir my_user@some-server:/remote/dir"

# run some other random command
with_password my_password "ssh my_user@some-server some_other_command"
```

The `interact` command seem to work sometimes when the ssh/rsync command closed the input at the correct time (maybe?), but it wasn't reliable.

Answer (score 2):

What about using passwordless logins with ssh keys?

You can create your keys with `ssh-keygen` then put your public key on the remote end: `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

You can even create keys with **passphrase** (if you want to add some kind of security) which you can load in your shell with `ssh-agent bash` enter you pass once, and it will keep your unlocked key in the memory for later password promptless logins.

Comment: I know about public key authentication and there are reasons why that won't work in my case.  Any ideas why the expect script is behaving unexpectedly?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the final here doc delimiter.

```
expect << END
spawn $2
expect *assword:*
send -- $1
interact
wait
END
```

Comment: Thnx for pointing that out, though that is there in the code; I made a typo transcribing it.

Comment: @aaron: I see that you added it back in your question, but it's after the closing curly brace. I assume it's also a transcription error.